# Why isn't an if condition working with .html() ? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I want to execute a jQuery condition based on the .html() method.
When I manually assign "A" to slot1 variable, my condition works.
However, when I assign the "A" to the slot1 variable from the #set1 element via the .html() method, the "A" is well assigned and shows in console.log as slot1 returns "A", but my condition doesn't work (#result stays stuck on "no").

Any idea how to get the condition working with the .html() method?

```
    // EXECUTING FUSION
$("#fusion").click(function(){
    slot1 = $("#set1").html();
    console.log(slot1);
    
    if (slot1 == "A") {
        $("#result").html("ok");
    }
    else {
        $("#result").html("no");
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `text()`. `html()` is for working with html code

Comment: Your condition works. If it didn't it would be a monumentally basic bug with Javascript. The problem is most likely because the value of `slot1` does not equal `A`. Have you debugged this? Try `console.log(slot1)` to see what the value is. I would guess it's an issue with whitespace causing additional characters in the string. Perhaps `let slot1 = $("#set1").html().trim();` would solve your issue.

Comment: Are you sure it's `"A"` and not maybe something like `" A "` (with whitespace)? Maybe try `slot1.trim() == "A"`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It did solve the issue thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code below works. Yours works too but **fails in some circumstances**. I believe the issues you are having is due to white space issues and how you are getting your 'slot1' input. If you are getting .html() from say, **a contenteditable div** like I have shown in my code below, then you need to remove the white spaces like I have done below because simply doing .trim() won't work since the spaces are encoded as **&nbsp** . If this helps you, an upvote would be appreciated

```js
                    $("#fusion").click(function(){
                        let slot1 = $("#set1").html();
                        console.log(slot1);
                        slot1 = slot1.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
                        console.log(slot1);
                        
                        if (slot1.trim() === "A") {
                            $("#result").html("ok");
                            console.log("ok");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#result").html("no");
                            console.log("no");
                        }
                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <div id="set1" contenteditable="true">This is where you type input.</div>
                <p id="result">Result</p>
                <button type="button" id="fusion" class="btn btn-primary buttonSignup" >CREATE ACCOUNT NOW<i class="iconRequired icon-chevron-right"></i></button>
```